# In Blazor client app (razor component), does every event triggered refresh the UI?

Tags: razor, .net-core, razor-pages, blazor, blazor-client-side

Does in Blazor client app every event triggered (mouse, keyboard, touch,...) cause the whole UI refreshed?
In the below example, on every key input, i is incremented while it not bound to oninput event.

```
<input type="text" @bind-value="@name" @bind-value:event="oninput"/>
@name
@ComputeResult()

@code {

string name;
int i=0;

public double ComputeResult()
{
    i = i + 1;
    return i;
}

}
```

Comment: Easy on the "razor component" renaming stuff, Blazor is just Blazor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only DOM elements that have changes get updated, not the entire UI. `Blazor` uses what they call a `Render Tree` to keep track of the elements that have changed and need to be updated. When an event fires, it regenerates the Render Tree and compares it to the old one to find changes, and then only updates the changed items in the render tree in the DOM.

> Components render into an in-memory representation of the browser's Document Object Model (DOM) called a render tree, which is used to update the UI in a flexible and efficient way.
>
> After the component is initially rendered, the component regenerates
>   its render tree in response to events. Blazor then compares the new
>   render tree against the previous one and applies any modifications to
>   the browser's Document Object Model (DOM).

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 3):

At the beginning, whenever you wanted to re-render your component, you had to call the StateHasChanged method which serves as the starting point of the rendering process. Nowadays, this is not necessary any longer. The StateHasChanged method is automatically called whenever a UI event, such as *change* or *click* is triggered. If you attach an empty event handler to a button control, and hit it, the StateHasChanged method is still called, which results in the re-rendering of your component, and consequently evaluating the expression `@ComputeResult()`. Note that this behavior can be altered by overriding the ComponentBase.ShouldRender method whose default returned value is *true*. Note that even if you overrides this method to return false, the first render always takes place.

Components are created only once, and they may be re-rendered multiple times. The re-rendering process and what is re-rendered is described in the answer by Kyle...